# Hide input for number of copies in Chrome printing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing, google-chrome-extension

I have a web system in Java with JSF 2.0, in a print I should not allow the user to change the number of copies. Then I developed a JNLP printing and then deletes file.

Now I'm trying another approach in Chrome browser.. For example, I inspected the input element in which are inserted the number of copies and marked as hidden.
How can I intercept this element through my system and put it as hidden? Would this be a good approach? Initially I thought of plugin but I think the ideal would be to use jquery or javascript in a generic way for me to easily apply to other browsers.

[image]

Comment: And what would stop the user from inspecting the page and updating the textbox value? If you look at sites that implement limits on printing, you will find out they require a plugin/software installed to print. Look at any of the online coupon sites to see what they do.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's a *bad* approach.

This is part of a privileged URL, `chrome://print/`. Extensions (and *most certainly* ordinary web code) cannot touch it unless you specifically set a dangerous flag (on every machine that uses the extension, manually).

Consider that this interface is subject to changes in newer Chrome versions as well, so it may break at any time.

Also, the user *always* has the option of invoking the system printing dialog (e.g. with Ctrl+Shift+P or with the link in the normal interface) that is not subject to your control.

In general, unfortunately Chrome does not expose any API to work with printing preferences, so trying to wrangle with this interface is probably a dead-end.